# Show: $\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}:P(X+Y=k)= \sum_{l\in \Bbb{Z}}P(X=l)\cdot P(Y=k-l)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with values in $\Bbb{Z}$
. Show:
$$\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}:P(X+Y=k)= \sum_{l\in \Bbb{Z}}P(X=l)\cdot P(Y=k-l)$$

My attempt:

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{l\in \Bbb{Z}}P(X=l)\cdot P(Y=k-l) &= \sum_{l\in \Bbb{Z}}P(X=l \cap Y=k-X) = \sum_{l\in \Bbb{Z}}P(X=l \cap Y+X=k)\\[1em] &=P(X\in Z \cap Y+X=k)=P(Y+X=k)
\end{aligned}

Comment: You need to take into account both $X$ and $Y$ have to be positive.  In particular the upper limit on the sum has to be $k-1$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry i dont understand. Where exactly is my mistake ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a mistake.  You just have to realize for $l\ge k$, $P(Y=k-l)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the underlying probability space.
Let $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)+Y(\omega)=k\}$. For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
let $B_{n}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)=n\}$ and $C_{n}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid Y(\omega)=k-n\}$.
It is routine to check that $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(B_{n}\cap C_{n}\right)$.
Moreover, for any $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $m\neq n$, $(B_{m}\cap C_{m})\bigcap(B_{n}\cap C_{n})=\emptyset$.
Therefore 
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A) & = & \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}P\left(B_{n}\cap C_{n}\right)\\
 & = & \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}P(B_{n})P(C_{n})\\
 & = & \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}P\left(\left[X=n\right]\right)P\left(\left[Y=k-n\right]\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that, the second equality follows from the fact that $X$ and
$Y$ are independent.